# SSH login and sudo are broken after running 'sudo cat sudoers', what could've happened?

Tags: ssh, rhel

I'm new to Linux and I have an RHEL VM that I am able to SSH into. I am SSH'ing from a Windows terminal. I wanted to check the `sudoers` file. I was able to login as normal, I then `cd`'d into `etc`, and ran `cat sudoers`. I got some form of access denied error. So I tried `sudo cat sudoers`. Typed in my sudo password, and started getting something like `Sorry, try again.` (this may not be the exact message, I no longer have access to the command history), even though the password was definitely correct, and sudo had been working up until now, in the same session.

Tried it again, and realized something was wrong. I left the SSH session after that, and tried to log back in a few minutes later. Now suddenly I'm getting `Permission denied, please try again.`, when I try to SSH back in, even with the correct password.

There was/is no indication that this is a temporary lockout due to password attempts (which would not make sense regardless because the password was always correct), and the issue has persisted for longer than any reasonable lockout period would be.

Is there *any way* that what I did messed with some login/permissions/password stuff?

Comment: From the commands you have mentioned, no. But how did you determine that "There was/is no indication that this is a temporary lockout due to password attempts"? Do you have another way to login to check the logs? Do you administer this system?

Comment: It gets worse: unfortunately, I don't have another way to login, and the admin (IT) is now telling me that they suddenly can't login locally either. I still have (non sudo) access to the system by running deployment scripts through an Azure DevOps agent that is installed on the machine. The only other things that happened to the machine semi-recently were that the same azure devops deployment agent downloaded some files into a folder within the /home/ directory. Note that none of these files were executable and nothing was 'ran'.

Comment: whatever happened, you didn't cause it by viewing sudoers file - something else caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

The first symptoms appeared when you tried to use `sudo` to view the sudoers file, so the problem existed before you invoked that command, it wasn't caused by the command.

Reading between the lines, I'm convinced that the sudoers file or the computer's general user authentication system was altered and this is displaying itself as you being unable to invoke `sudo` and no one being able to log directly into the computer.  Your only access is indirectly through a pre-configured deploy/devops service.

I would expect a broken sudoers file to prevent `sudo` commands from working, but I wouldn't expect it to cause trouble for direct login/authentication sessions.  That's why I suggested the issue may be related to the auth services rather than the sudoers file.

You may have to suspend the VM and attach its root filesystem to another VM so you can examine the logfiles and perhaps fix configuration errors.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that authentication was somehow setup 'incorrectly' from the beginning? I wrote out everything that happened in the session that triggered this, and it sounds like it almost certainly could not have caused any harm. Also, when you say logfiles, any immediate places to look?

Comment: There's a variety of ways to configure a Linux VM to authenticate users, some perform local authentication, others use a centralized service like LDAP or Active Directory to authenticate.  There isn't just one way, so the number of possible errors is too large for me to make good guesses.  Logs tend to be in the `/var/log` directory, but some programs (including authentication clients) may write their logfiles in other places.  Under the `/var` directory in the majority of cases, but other places are possible.